# How to get Usage ID or a similer attribute for a USB (HID Usage ID) connected device in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, hid

Is there a way to get **HID Usage ID** for a **USB device** in **Linux** ?
I can use `lsusb` to get PID and VID but in device driver development we cannot use PID as it is different in different devices which are run in a particularly same mode. When thinking from windows developments point of view HID Usage ID is unique for this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage pages supported by a device must be parsed out of the device's report descriptor. Windows does this for you when you call `HidD_GetPreparsedData`. There are two ways to get the report descriptor from the device:

1. Open the `/dev/hidrawN` device node and use the `HIDIOCGRDESCSIZE` and `HIDIOCGRDESC` ioctls to get the report descriptor.
2. Read the report descriptor out of sysfs by opening the `report_descriptor` file in the device's sysfs directory. This property is also available through the udev library.

Once you have the raw report descriptor you can use a library like [hidrd](https://github.com/DIGImend/hidrd) to parse it.

Comment: I followed your instructions. It works for me. Tanks @Reilly Grant.